# audacius warning

Tags: audacious

After

```
audacious -p song.mp3
```

I got the following:

> ** WARNING **
>
> Audacious has detected that your ALSA device has a broken timer.  A workaround is being used to prevent CPU overload. Please report this problem to your Linux distributor or to the ALSA developers.

Is it important? How to solve it?

I'm using **Audacious 2.4.4 (Ubuntu package)** with

```
Linux vaio 3.0.0-16-generic-pae #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 19:24:01 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The Audacious developers are just informing you that their program has detected a bug in your audio device (or its interface).  Because it's a known type of bug, they've even added code to handle it.  If your system has audio drivers other than ALSA, have you tried using them?  (I don't remember how to change the audio driver on the `audacious` command line, but if you launch the GUI then it's in the Preferences menu.)

Comment: @dg99, thanks.When I try to change using *Preferences*, I got on the terminal `pulseaudio: Failed to connect to server: Connexion Refused  Output plugin failed to load: PulseAudio Output Plugin Falling back to: ALSA Output Plugin`

Comment: Ah, that just means that PulseAudio isn't running on your machine.  Can you check if the PulseAudio Ubuntu package is installed?  If so, try launching the daemon as yourself (not as root): `/path/to/pulseaudio --start`. You'll eventually want to add it to the auto-startup programs.